# Incrementally add seconds of a timestamp column grouped by ID in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have a dataframe that is essentially a time series data.

```
    Timestamp <- c("1/27/2015 18:28:16","1/27/2015 18:28:17","1/27/2015 18:28:19","1/27/2015 18:28:20","1/27/2015 18:28:23","1/28/2015 22:43:08","1/28/2015 22:43:09","1/28/2015 22:43:13","1/28/2015 22:43:15","1/28/2015 22:43:16"
) 
    ID <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B")
    v1<- c(1.70,1.71,1.77,1.79,1.63,7.20,7.26,7.16,7.18,7.18) 
    df <- data.frame(Timestamp ,ID,v1)

Timestamp            ID             v1
1/27/2015 18:28:16   A              1.70
1/27/2015 18:28:17   A              1.71
1/27/2015 18:28:19   A              1.77
1/27/2015 18:28:20   A              1.79
1/27/2015 18:28:23   A              1.63
1/28/2015 22:43:08   B              7.20
1/28/2015 22:43:09   B              7.26
1/28/2015 22:43:13   B              7.16
1/28/2015 22:43:15   B              7.18
1/28/2015 22:43:16   B              7.18
```

Since I dont really care about the timestamp, I was thinking of creating a column called interval to plot this data in one plot.

I am wrongly creating the interval column by doing this

```
df$interval <- cut(df$Timestamp, breaks="sec")
```

I want to incrementally add the "secs" of the timestamp and put it in the interval column and this should by grouped by ID. By this I mean, Everytime it has a new ID, the interval column resets to 1 and then incrementally adds the timestamp (secs).

My desired output

```
Timestamp            ID             v1      Interval
1/27/2015 18:28:16   A              1.70      1
1/27/2015 18:28:17   A              1.71      2
1/27/2015 18:28:19   A              1.77      4
1/27/2015 18:28:20   A              1.79      5
1/27/2015 18:28:23   A              1.63      8
1/28/2015 22:43:08   B              7.20      1
1/28/2015 22:43:09   B              7.26      2
1/28/2015 22:43:13   B              7.16      6 
1/28/2015 22:43:15   B              7.18      8
1/28/2015 22:43:16   B              7.18      9
```

I also would like to plot this using ggplot with interval vs v1 by ID and so we get 2 time series in the same plot. I will then extract features from it.

Please help me how to work around this problem so that I can apply it to a larger dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution with `data.table`:

For the data:

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)
df$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df$Timestamp, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
df[, Interval := as.numeric(difftime(Timestamp, .SD[1, Timestamp], units='secs') + 1)   , by=ID]
```

which outputs:

```
> df
              Timestamp ID   v1 Interval
 1: 2015-01-27 18:28:16  A 1.70        1
 2: 2015-01-27 18:28:17  A 1.71        2
 3: 2015-01-27 18:28:19  A 1.77        4
 4: 2015-01-27 18:28:20  A 1.79        5
 5: 2015-01-27 18:28:23  A 1.63        8
 6: 2015-01-28 22:43:08  B 7.20        1
 7: 2015-01-28 22:43:09  B 7.26        2
 8: 2015-01-28 22:43:13  B 7.16        6
 9: 2015-01-28 22:43:15  B 7.18        8
10: 2015-01-28 22:43:16  B 7.18        9
```

Then for `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Interval, y=v1, color=ID)) + geom_line()
```

and the graph:

[image]

Comment: wow that is exactly what I need. I ran your code in my large data set and it works like charm. Thank you so much. I just need one more small help. I get the plots of the ID's overlapped in my bigger data set. Is there a way we can place them right next to each other may be in a window or sections in ggplot by ID? Please let me know if I am unclear on what I want. I also made edits to my output table upon what you said.

Comment: Your are very welcome :). Glad I could be of help! Sure, you can do it. Just use this:  `ggplot(df, aes(x=Interval, y=v1, color=ID)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(. ~ ID)` and they will be plotted as facets i.e. in sections.

Comment: You can see more about facets [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_%28ggplot2%29/)

Comment: Facets!!.. Excellent and beautiful plots!!! Man.. you saved a lot of time for me. :) I truly appreciate it. I am going to extend this work to many variables and play around with it.

Comment: They are indeed! `ggplot2` is a wonderful library! You are very welcome. I am really happy I was able to help :)